# Next Js take several params in the root

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, seo, url-routing

Suppose, I want to take params `region` and `lang` in URLs like:
`https://root.com/{region}/{lang}`
`https://root.com/{region}/{lang}/school`

How do I do that? I tried Dynamic Routing, but it doesn't seem to work with the root index.js. How should I structure my folder tree?
`/pages/[region]/[lang]/index.js` Doesn't look like a valid one.

Answer (score 0):

In your default exported component in `/pages/[region]/[lang]/index.js` you can use [next/router - useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter).

The query object will contain the `region` and `lang` parameters.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export const Page = () => {
  const { query } = useRouter();
  console.log({ query });
  
  return <>My index page!</>;
};

export default Page;
```

to get the `/school` path simply add a school.js file in the same folder as `index.js` and get query params with useRouter as above.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I believe there are couple ways,

Use dynamic routing for URLs like [https://root.com/{region}/{lang}](https://root.com/%7Bregion%7D/%7Blang%7D).

- Create a "pages" folder with subfolders for each region and language. Inside each subfolder, have an "index.js" file.
- Use a library like "next-routes" or "react-router" for routing.